# iPod goes to sleep when only accelerometer is used

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a problem with my current game.In this game i have to move a pouch using accelerometer , but the problem is when i use only accelerometer (without any touch in screen) iPod screen become dim and then goes to sleep.

So is there any parameter which i need to set to refrain iPod/iPhone from going to sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable auto-sleep:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

To re-enable:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
```

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled